# Why won't my component show up in the layout editor

Tags: visualforce-component, page-layout

I made a component that I wanted to add to the Account layout, but in the layout editor, it doesn't list my component under "Components".

What's going on? How do I get it to show up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have to do is to include it in a VisualForce page.
Set the page `standardController=Account` and turn off the header and sidebar ie:
`sidebar="false" showHeader="false"`
Then place your component in the page.

Now you'll see your new page containing the component show up in the Account layout editor.